# How do I plot a histogram of two different columns on a single bar chart?

Tags: spotfire

I have just begun using Spotfire, and want to plot a histogram of two columns in one dataset on the same bar chart. When I put the two columns on the x axis, Spotfire nests them automatically i.e. <[cat1] NEST [cat2]>. How do I turn this option off i.e. something like <[cat1], [cat2]>? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn off nesting. A histogram with 2 different columns not nested doesn't mean anything. How are you comparing the data? You can't see if the data is skewed or not with two columns. Either use 2 histograms, or create a property control where users can select the column they want to see., or play around with trellis settings.

Answer (score 0):

your question seems to be "how do I plot a histogram of two different columns on a single bar chart?" so I made an edit.

put both of your expressions on the value axis and then Color By `(Column Names)`.